# JPA bi-directional @OneToMany not populating Foreign Key on reference table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables "Action" and "Action_Function" where later has Composite Primary Key (Action_id & Sequence_nr).
But, when I execute **repository.save(action)** the value **Action_id** column on **Action_Function** table insert as **null**.

I am using Spring Boot 3 with Spring Data JPA(Hibernate).

### Action

Action_id (pk)

### Action_Function

Action_id (pk)
Sequence_nr (pk)   <-- Sequence_nr comes from UI(DTO)

I am using @IdClass for the convenience of MapStruct DTO to entity mapping, hence not using @Embeddable.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTION")
public class Action {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Action_id")
    private Integer actionId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "action", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ActionFunction> actionFunctions = new HashSet<>();

    // Other fields
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTION_FUNCTION")
@IdClass(ActionFunctionId.class)
public class ActionFunction {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Action_id")
    private Integer actionId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Sequence_nr")
    private Integer sequenceNr;

    // here, added insertable and updatable false otherwise JPA tries to add two Action_id 
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Action_id")
    @MapsId("actionId")
    private Action action;

    // other fields
}
```

```
public class ActionFunctionId implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4601022716234244483L;

    private Integer actionId;

    private Integer sequenceNr;

    // Equals & hashCode
}
```

Here is how I am populating entities, a simple representation of my current code where they get populated using MapStruct.

```
@Service
public class ActionServiceImpl {

        public void saveAction(){
            ActionFunction actionFunction = new ActionFunction();
            actionFunction.setSequenceNr(1);

            ActionFunction actionFunction2 = new ActionFunction();
            actionFunction2.setSequenceNr(2);

            Action action = new Action();
            action.setActionFunctions(Set.of(actionFunction, actionFunction2));
            Action actionSaved = actionRepository.save(action);
        }
    }
```

ActionRepository is simple Spring Data Jpa Repository. We are following DDD and these two entities are part of same Aggregate, hence we can have one Repository with root aggregate Action.

```
@Repository
 public interface ActionRepository extends JpaRepository<Action, Integer> {
        
        }
```

I really appreciate some advice how to fix this.

Comment: Please add the rest of the code where you execute the save
You must first save your Action entity, then This Action object must go inside the ActionFunction object, and you save the ActionFunction

Comment: @borchvm Thanks for your reply. I have added Service (a simpler version) and Repository class.
But, our expectation is when we do save(action), cascade=CascadeType.ALL on OneToMany entities, that's why we are not saving Action and ActionFunction entity separately.

Comment: JPA is doing what you asked, and is cascading the Persist operation to your referenced ActionFunction instances or they would not be being inserted. If you check out those ActionFunction instances, you'd see that the property that controls the "Action_id" column, action, is null, forcing JPA to insert null into that foreign key. You'll need to check the JPA contracts, as your expectations on what should happen when you set a OneToMany relationship is wrong. JPA tutorials should cover this, but you are required to set both sides, or at least the owning side of relationships

Comment: Thanks @Chris , Can I force JPA to insert on Action table first and then insert on ActionFunction table. I can live with uni-directional OneToMany mapping on Action entity if needed.

Comment: Not sure why you need to - to make what you've got work, you just need to go through the actionFunctions collection and ensure they point to the action. JPA will then order inserts for you based on the relationship. JPA would also handle the unidirectional 1:M for you too and update the FK in the ActionFunction rows as needed, but this is not usually done as the child->Parent reference more accurately reflects the fk structure.

Comment: @Chris For DDD design, we have only one Repository for Action and cannot do save(action) then populate actionFunctions collection with managed "action" entity. Both Action and ActionFunction are part of same aggregate and Action is the root here, and expectation is ActionFunction operation cascade from Action. I tried populating Action entity on actionFunction collection then do save(action), but still Action_id on ACTION_FUNCTION table still null.

Comment: oh my, you've got insertable = false, updatable = false on the relationship, so there is nothing in this code that sets the Action_id column - I didn't realize you were trying to make it your primary key as well! The model is fine, the mappings are not - look up tutorials on JPA 2(.x?)'s derived IDs. I'll try to give an example answer

Comment: @Chris As you suggested, I removed "insertable = false, updatable = false" and added MapsId on ManyToOne side, also updated my original post with this. I am still not seeing Action_id getting populated. I also looked up JPA 3.1 specification for MapsId and the mapping seems okay. Not sure what else am i missing. Wondering if its because Action_id on Action entity is  of GenerationType.IDENTITY, which Hibernate does not control? I am out of clue here!

Comment: You have not yet set the ActionFunction.action reference. If it is null, that is what gets inserted.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for keeping up with this. I tried setting action on each actionFunction, but still no luck. But, I have found an alternative solution and will post it below shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA added options to allow deriving the ID in a child entity from the parent. To have your child use the parent's ID as part of its compound ID, you just need to mark the relationship with the MapsId annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTION_FUNCTION")
@IdClass(ActionFunctionId.class)
public class ActionFunction {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Action_id")
    private Integer actionId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Sequence_nr")
    private Integer sequenceNr;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    //This will have JPA set the actionId property using the action.id value
    @MapsId("actionId")
    private Action action;

    // other fields
}
```

Comment: This helped me to narrow down and find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found a working solution.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTION")
public class Action implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Action_id")
    private Integer actionId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "action", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ActionFunction> actionFunctions = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTION_FUNCTION", schema = "dbo")
@IdClass(ActionFunctionId.class)
public class ActionFunction implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Action_id", referencedColumnName = "Action_id")
    private Action action;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Sequence_nr")
    private Integer sequenceNr;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ActionFunctionId implements Serializable {

    private Integer action;

    private Integer sequenceNr;
}
```

**JUnit Test**

```
    @Test
    void createAction(){

        ActionFunction actionFunction = new ActionFunction();
        actionFunction.setSequenceNr(1);

        Action action = new Action();
        action.setActionFunctions(Set.of(actionFunction));

        actionFunction.setAction(action);

        Action actionSaved = actionRepository.save(action);
    }
```

[Records on database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI3Ra.png)

Comment: actionFunction.setAction(action); is what I was telling you all along was missing.

Comment: @Chris I tried it too, for some reason it did not work. But, I really appreciate your help and time. It worked when I added Id annotation on the Action entity inside ActionFunction class.